# Create subdomains for tags and categories

Tags: categories, tags, subdomains

I'd like to find a way to make subdomain addresses work for some of my important tags and categories. For instance foo.thesite.com would show content for thesite.com/category/foo.

I've been trying to make this working using my .htaccess file and the DNS but I can't get it to work properly.

Making the subdomain forward to the right URL is just a matter of the right DNS settings, but then I also want to make sure the site shows it as foo.thesite.com.

Can anyone provide some ideas on how to make this work?

**Update - April 6:** I found one partial solution. If you have full domain DNS control and you have the CURL DNS option you can add a subdomain and point it to the category or tag page. The catch is that when I did this, clicking links leaves the URL as foo.thesite.com, and the title somehow doesn't work--instead of a title I get the URL as the page title.

Any thoughts on this, alternatives, or ideas on how to format the .htaccess rules?

Answer (score 3):

This plugin will help you:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-subdomains/

Also, wp_redirect could be helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706672/wordpress-tags-redirect-to-subdomains

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid adding more plugins to my site, and I'd like to make it work for tags too, but the second link you provided is interesting. I'll see if I can make the .htaccess rule work for my circumstance.

Comment: As it turns out I couldn't make that work. The .htaccess rules don't work for me either. The redirect is a good idea, but without a work .htaccess rule it doesn't accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 0):

this plugin does it:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/main-category-as-subdomain
you can also choose custom themes for each category